# Tomcat/Eclipse: disable HttpSession serialization during context reload

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jsf, tomcat

I'm getting `InvalidObjectException: Could not find a SessionFactory named: null` after restart of tomcat server.

I've found some possible solution:

> *This exception occurs if you try to serialize a disconnected Hibernate Session and deserialize it in a different VM, or, if the
>   classloader has restarted, for example, during hot redeployment in
>   your application server or web container. This is especially visible
>   in Tomcat. In application servers, always use JNDI to store the
>   SessionFactory, as documented. In Tomcat or other web containers,
>   **disable HttpSession serialization during context reload**. This has side effects, explained in the web container's documentation.*

How can I do it? Disable HttpSession serialization during context reload?

*Note:* I'm using Tomcat7 in Eclipse.

**UPDATE:**

I've tried enable this tag in `context.xml`:

`<Manager pathname="" />`

and yes, the exception disappears, but I lose persistent sessions, so I have to login again after tomcat server restart.

Do I understand session persistence well, if I believe, that session should be kept (and I mustn't create a new one by login) after tomcat restart in e.g. JSF application?

**UPDATE2 (session manager):**

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name="userManager")
public class UserManager implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private transient HttpSession session;
  private String username;
  private String password;
  private User user;

  public String login() {
    // here is seraching for user in database (based on username and password)

    if (user != null) {
      FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
      session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
      session.setAttribute("id", user.getId());
      session.setAttribute("username", user.getName());
      ...
      return "success";
    } 
  }

  public String logout() {
    user = null;
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
    ...     
    session.invalidate();
    return "success";
  }
  // getters and setters ----------------------------------------------------
}
```

And my `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC 
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=RXP</property>
  <property name="connection.username">user</property>
  <property name="connection.password">password</property>
  <property name="connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect</property>
  <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

  <mapping class="tables.User"/>

 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And my **session factory**:

```
public final class DaoSF implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
  private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

  public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    try {
      Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
      configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
      serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();        
      sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
      return sessionFactory;
    }
    catch (HibernateException he) { 
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to turn it of by putting:

```
<Manager pathname="" />
```

within the Context section in the Tomcat configuration file.

See the Tomcat documentation:
*Configuration Reference* > *The Manager Component* > *Disable Session Persistence*

- [Version 7.0](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html#Disable_Session_Persistence)
- [Version 8.0](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/manager.html#Disable_Session_Persistence)

Comment: Yep, I've tried it a and exception dissapears. But the session is not stored now and I have to login again every time, I restart the tomcat server (take a look at my updated question please)......

Comment: If you don't want to turn off session persistence, then you have to fix the objects in your session, i.e. you have to make them serializable (implement java.io.Serializable) (see [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html#Persistence_Across_Restarts).)

Comment: All my beans are serializabled :( (`implements Serializable ... private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;`)

Comment: How do you manage sessions? Are you using JNDI for this? If yes, it might help to switch to a session manager that uses thread local storage and keeps the session factory out of Tomcat's reach.

Comment: It would probably help if you could post a full stacktrace of the InvalidObjectException to better diagnose which object is causing the problem. And are you sure it's "current_session_context_class" and not "hibernate.current_session_context_class"?

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your answer, it solves the original question :-)

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by Codo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11280040/642706) is correct.

Here is an example of implementing the mentioned tag.

In your web app’s `META-INF` folder, in the `context.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="">
    <Manager pathname=""/>
</Context>
```